# Using spark with latest aws-java-sdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-java-sdk

We are currently using spark 2.1 with hadoop 2.7.3 and I know and can't believe that spark still requires aws-java-sdk version 1.7.4. We are using a maven project and I was wondering if there is any way to setup libraries or my environment to be able to use spark 2.1 along with other applications that use the latest aws-java-sdk? I guess it's the same thing as asking if it's possible to setup a workflow that uses different versions of the aws-java-sdk and then when I want to run the jar on a cluster I could just point to the latest aws-java-sdk. I know I could obviously maintain to separate projects one for spark and one for pure sdk work but I'd like to just have them in the same project.

Answer (score 0):

> use spark 2.1 along with other applications that use the latest aws-java-sdk

You can try to use the Maven Shade Plugin when you create your JAR, then ensure the user classpath is before the Hadoop classpath (`spark.executor.userClassPathFirst`). This will ensure you're loading all dependencies included by Maven, not what's provided by Spark

I've done this with Avro before, but I know that the AWS SDK has more to it